# How can i make a tactile feedback on physical button pressed?

Tags: android

Actually i'm developing an app for devices like

Honeywell EDA50K and EDA60K and the client asked me if it was possible to add a tactile feedback on physical buttons.

After looking some documentation on the honeywell website i've found nothing that i could use, so is it possible to add a tactile feedback to physical button? i would add something like a light vibration or just a simple sound something like when someone press a key on softKeyboard.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how can i do it?

Comment: If the user enables vibration in android, doesn't it already vibrate when you press a key on soft keyboard?

Comment: @Steven yes, but i'm trying to archive it by pressind a physical button.

Comment: And what is the physical button used for? Is it the back button? Home button?

Comment: @Steven no, actually the device has entire physical keyboard, try to google EDA50K

Comment: Try my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to put this in your activity class.

```
//put this somewhere in your onCreate method or someplace else
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work, in debug it doesn't even enter in the onKeyDown method